# How to get IOS to ask users whether they want to allow application to use their location everytime?

Tags: ios

If we try to access the user's location, iOS will tell the user that our application wants to use their location.

If I do this

```
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

An alert will show.

However, that only happens once.

It looks like some variable or default must have been set up once that display pops out.

How do I reset those default so that next time my app wants to use location users will be asked again?

Google map can displays that again and again.

Answer (score 1):

It's only showed on the first time and there's nothing you can do to change that. What you can do is ask your users to allow it on settings.

You can check if your app has permissions by checking:

```
[CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]
```

From the docs:

> The user can enable or disable location services from the Settings application by toggling the Location Services switch in General.
>
> You should check the return value of this method before starting location updates to determine whether the user has location services enabled for the current device. If this method returns NO and you start location updates anyway, the Core Location framework prompts the user to confirm whether location services should be reenabled.

Comment: It's not the iOS alert. It's a custom one, as I said.

Comment: @SeptiadiAgus That's a web interface. Web is different than Native.

Answer (score 1):

#### It's Apple that asks them for permission, not you

Translation: You don't have any control over that part of the process. The little popup:

[image: location]

is only shown by Apple when you first ask for it - so the user always feels in control. After they accept for the first time, Apple assumes they are OK with your app getting their location information from their device, and won't show it again*.

<sub>*Unless they specifically go into Settings and disable Location Services for you app.</sub>